# Small Words on the side of Big Words. Is it a manga thing or a japanese thing?

Tags: meaning, words, furigana

I'm interested on learning Japanese and I was curious on how this works. I picked a japanese manga for curiosity and saw this on a balloom speech.

Why there is small words on the side of the big ones?

[image]

Comment: That's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The small writing is called [*furigana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana) in Japanese, and is also known as [*ruby text*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_character) in English.  These are provided as phonetic guides to show the pronunciations of the bigger characters.

*Furigana* are written out in [*kana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana), the phonetic Japanese [syllabaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabary) (a syllabary is like an alphabet, but each character represents a whole syllable).  There are two kinds of *kana*: [*hiragana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana), used for most native terms, and the individual characters tend to be rounder; and [*katakana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana), used for some native terms and more for borrowed terms, and the individual characters tend to be more angular.  Imagine it as a little like `UPPER CASE` and `lower case` for the Latin alphabet -- two sets of glyphs (characters), where each pair has the same sound value.

The bigger blocky characters are called [*kanji*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji).  Kanji are complicated and take time to learn, much like English spelling rules only more complex.  A kanji character can also have multiple possible pronunciations, depending on context, which makes things even more complicated.

Since manga readers are often kids who haven't finished learning all the kanji yet, manga publishers often provide *furigana* so kids can still read the text.